# Is Zilpha Horace Delaney's or Salish's daughter?

Tags: character, taboo

At one point during the course of [*Taboo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3647998/) I learned that Zilpha isn't actually James's sister, but only his half-sister. But I don't actually recall it being said from whose side of the parentage, although I doubt it was kept unclarified and I probably just missed it (but am willing to be surprised).

On the one hand it makes sense for her to be Horace Delaney's daughter, since she was expected to inherit his stuff, especially Nootka Sound, which she already negotiated to sell to the East India Company. But on the other hand, seeing how James's relation to his mother Salish is much more "mystical" and she is generally the more "interesting" or significant parent from a plot perspective, it would make more sense for Zilpha to be Salish's daughter, especially with regards to James's and Zilpha's incestuous relationship and the "wilder" nature sleeping in Zilpha.

So **when was it actually clarified if Zilpha was Horace Delaney's or Salish's daughter**, if it was? (I doubt we know anything about her other parent, though?)

Comment: Zilpha is Horace Delaney's child by his second marriage and James Delaney's younger half-sister. Married to Thorne Geary. A devout Christian.  [reference](http://taboo.wikia.com/wiki/Zilpha_Geary)

Comment: @irsha If this is a valid source, you might wanna add this as an answer.

Comment: But it doesn't answer _"when was it actually clarified if Zilpha was Horace Delaney's or Salish's daughter"_